# How can I set data type from variable value in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typing

I am very new to TypeScript and related technologies. :wink:

---

I use Nest.js and `cache-manager`. In `cache-manager`, I can use `await this.cacheManager.get<type>(key)` to get a key value. The `type` needs be replaced with real type (obviously).

As `cache-manager` saves all values as strings, I want to enforce the type of the value. I create another record in `cache-manager` under `key/type` value. As this is a string, how can I pass it as a data type in `this.cacheManager.get<type>()`?

**Update**

Here’s a more visual example of what I want to do using `switch()` … there should be a more concise way to do it using some kind of dynamic typings (or however it is called).

```
async getValue(name: string, type?: string): Promise<boolean | number | object | string> {
  type ||= await this.cacheManager.get<string>(`${name}/type`) || 'string'

  switch (type) {
    case 'boolean':
      return await this.cacheManager.get<boolean>(name)
    case 'number':
      return await this.cacheManager.get<number>(name)
    case 'object':
      return JSON.parse(await this.cacheManager.get<string>(name))
    default:
      return await this.cacheManager.get<string>(name)
  }
}
```

Comment: You could replace the whole `switch` statement with just `return await this.cacheManager.get(name)`, since all four branches do the same thing. They just have different type annotations, which are erased during compilation anyway. The `cacheManager.get` method has no information at runtime about what type parameter you called it with, so it can't return different things depending on that type parameter. Assuming this is not the behaviour you want, you have to think about how to do what you want in Javascript, and then write type annotations for it; Typescript = Javascript + type annotations.

Comment: Indeed, I could, but the type would be string (e.g. `'true'` string instead of `true` boolean). They are not only _differently annotated_, but they are converted (e.g. string to boolean), b/c I can work with them as booleans, not as strings. Basically, all I want is to create a type annotation (or simply _type_) from a string value (e.g. `'number'` string → `number` type).

Comment: They are not converted; the code you have written does not convert them. Type annotations do not affect what your code actually does when you run it in any way.

Comment: Well, `cacheManager` is an instance of `cache-manager` (actually, it is imported as `import {Cache} from 'cache-manager'`) and `cache-manager` does the conversion.

Comment: Then you can replace the whole `switch` statement with a single `return` statement, as I said. (Or not, now that you've edited to use `JSON.parse` in one branch; but as currently written, your code only needs two branches, not four.)

Comment: I don’t think so. `cache-manager` stores all values as strings (not as numbers, booleans or objects). … … As for the `object`, I believe it needs to be post-processed anyway, but I am not so sure for numbers and booleans. … … Another way to describe what I want is a comparison to methods like `toString()` or `parseInt()`: those convert values from one type to another, however, I want to ‘convert’ a string value to type where string value is same as the type name (keyword).

Comment: Either `this.cacheManager.get` does the conversion for you, or it does not. If it does the conversion, then the type annotations do not change that fact, and you don't need three separate branches with different type annotations, it will do the conversion just the same if you reduce those to one branch. If it does not do the conversion, then the type annotations do not change that fact, and you must write actual Javascript code to do the conversions you want. Either way, the code you have shown here is not sensible Javascript because you have three branches which do exactly the same thing.

Comment: It does the conversion _only when I supply the desired type via `<type>`_, otherwise it defaults to `<string>`; in `await this.cacheManager.get<number>(name)`, `get()` is describe in my text editor as `(method) Cache.get<number>(key: string): Promise<number>` ([src](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/cache-manager/index.d.ts#L72)). If I run `typeof` on the returned value, it is `number` in this case.

Comment: It fundamentally cannot do what you are describing, since you are not "supplying" the desired type *to the method*, you are only supplying it *to the Typescript compiler*. It is erased from the source code before the method is ever called. It is described that way in your text editor only because you *told* the compiler that it returns a `number` with your annotation; you telling the compiler that it returns a number does not cause it to return a number, and you not telling the compiler that it returns a number would not cause the same method with the same argument to return something else.

Comment: Okay. Then the only way to accomplish this (type assertion) to use a `switch()` with individual cases for each data type?

Comment: Going by the type declarations in your GitHub link, what you ought to do is delete the `case 'number':` and `case 'boolean':` branches, and change the type parameter in the `default:` branch to `string | number | boolean`.

Comment: Or can you find a more efficient and/or concise way to write this? You could post an answer; I am happy to accept it. :wink:

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using a generic? Something like this:

```
async getCacheValue<T>(name: string): Promise<T> {
 return await this.cacheManager.get<T>(name)
}
```

Then call the method like this:

```
getCacheValue<type>(name)
```

I'm not at all familar with Nest.JS or cache-manager so sorry if I haven't understood but this might point you in the right direction

Comment: Well, yeah, I meant something like that, however, I am not (yet) familiar with the generics really. However, see the updated OP: I replaced the `switch()` with a function I currently use. And the question is not really Nest.js nor `cach-manager` related; its a pure TS and typings problem. :wink: … Could you find a way to define the generic types with the `type` variable definition in mind please?